# How to get value from a xml file if there are multiple tags with same namespace

Tags: java, xml, pom.xml, xmlstarlet

i want to get version of a maven surefire plugin from an effective pom file of maven.
it looks like this a below xml file. It has multiple  under  and i want to fetch plugin information out to get version information.
i am able to get this information if just on project is present and no projects tag is present. using the below command.

xmlstarlet sel -t -v "*:project/*:build/*:plugins/*:plugin[*:artifactId='maven-surefire-plugin']/*:version" epom.xml

```html
     <plugin>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.22.0</version   
</plugin>
```

```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2022-08-01T11:57:29+05:30            -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- 

====================================================================== -->
<projects>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
..................
    </project>
    
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.22.0</version   
            </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
    </projects>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input file *is* formatted correctly (and not missing the closing `>` for `<version`, as in *both* examples); I presume your question is:

> *How to get the `<version>` of a `<project>`-child, under a `<projects>`-parent*

I would use something like:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel  
  -N e="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" \
  -t -m "/projects" \
  -m "e:project" \
  -v "e:build/e:plugins/e:plugin[e:artifactId='maven-surefire-plugin']/e:version" \
  --break \
  -n file.xml
```

- `-N` for **n**amespace, using the letter `e` as a randomly chosen custom prefix for later use
- `-t -m "/projects"` matches the outer `<projects>`-node
  *(no custom namespace prefix yet)*
- `-m "e:project"` matches all `<project>`-nodes, that have the specified namespace
- `-v "e:build/e:plugins/e:plugin[e:artifactId='maven-surefire-plugin']/e:version"` gives the `<version>`-value, for all `<project>`-nodes that contain an `<artifactId>`-node with the 'maven-surefire-plugin' content (text)
- `--break` prevents newlines in the output for `<project>`-nodes without the specified `<artifactId>` (plugin)